# (HTML + JavaScript + BootStrap) Table With Delete Button Won't Show up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, delete-row, bootstrap-table

[Correct Solution with different context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXFRi.png) |
[My Solution, table won't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRvKe.png)

I can't seem to figure out why my table won't show after I added a new column, any inputs?
Sorry if my code is a mess, I'm still learning. I had to tweak my professors lecture examples to figure this out

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#AddSaleButton').click(function() {
    var PlayerName = $('#PlayerName').val();
    var Goals = parseInt($('#GoalNum').val());
    var Assists = parseInt($('#AssistQuantity').val());
    $('#OrderTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + PlayerName + '</td><td>' + Goals + '</td><td>' + Assists + '</td><td></td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger DeleteRow" data-product="' + PlayerName + '" data-quantity="' + Goals + 'data-assist="' + Assists + '>Delete Order</button></td></tr>');

    switch (PlayerName) {
      case "Erling":
        var EachPlayerSum = parseInt($('#ETotal').text());
        EachPlayerSum = EachPlayerSum + Goals + Assists;
        var TotalEveryone = parseInt($('#TotalEveryone').text());
        TotalEveryone = TotalEveryone + Goals + Assists;

        $('#ETotal').text(EachPlayerSum);
        $('#TotalEveryone').text(TotalEveryone);

        break;

      case "Phil":
        var EachPlayerSum = parseInt($('#PTotal').text());
        EachPlayerSum = EachPlayerSum + Goals + Assists;

        var TotalEveryone = parseInt($('#TotalEveryone').text());
        TotalEveryone = TotalEveryone + Goals + Assists;

        $('#PTotal').text(EachPlayerSum);
        $('#TotalEveryone').text(TotalEveryone);

        break;

      case "Jack":
        var EachPlayerSum = parseInt($('#JTotal').text());
        EachPlayerSum = EachPlayerSum + Goals + Assists;

        var TotalEveryone = parseInt($('#TotalEveryone').text());
        TotalEveryone = TotalEveryone + Goals + Assists;

        $('#JTotal').text(EachPlayerSum);
        $('#TotalEveryone').text(TotalEveryone);

        break;
    }

    $('AddSaleModal').modal('hide');

    $('#AddOrderToast').show();

    $('#GoalNum').val('');
    $('#AssistQuantity').val('');
    $('#PlayerName').prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#AddOrderToast').hide();
    }, 3000);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.DeleteRow', function() {
    var PlayerName = $(this).attr('data-product');
    var Goals = parseInt($(this).attr('data-quantity'));
    var Assists = parseInt($(this).attr('data-assist'));

    switch (PlayerName) {
      case "Erling":
        var EachPlayerSum = parseInt($('#ETotal').text());
        EachPlayerSum = EachPlayerSum - Goals - Assists;
        var TotalEveryone = parseInt($('#TotalEveryone').text());
        TotalEveryone = TotalEveryone - Goals - Assists;

        $('#ETotal').text(EachPlayerSum);
        $('#TotalEveryone').text(TotalEveryone);

        break;

      case "Phil":
        var EachPlayerSum = parseInt($('#PTotal').text());
        EachPlayerSum = EachPlayerSum - Goals - Assists;

        var TotalEveryone = parseInt($('#TotalEveryone').text());
        TotalEveryone = TotalEveryone - Goals - Assists;

        $('#PTotal').text(EachPlayerSum);
        $('#TotalEveryone').text(TotalEveryone);

        break;

      case "Jack":
        var EachPlayerSum = parseInt($('#JTotal').text());
        EachPlayerSum = EachPlayerSum - Goals - Assists;

        var TotalEveryone = parseInt($('#TotalEveryone').text());
        TotalEveryone = TotalEveryone - Goals - Assists;

        $('#Jtotal').text(EachPlayerSum);
        $('#TotalEveryone').text(TotalEveryone);

        break;
    }
    var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr'); //parent parent works too instead of closest
    tableRow.remove();

    $('#DeleteOrderToast').show();

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#DeleteOrderToast').hide();
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffca1c">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Manchester City Soccer Team</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-light">

  <div class="container-lg mt-5">
    <div class="row mb-3 text-center">
      <h1>Manchester City Soccer Team</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3 w-50 mx-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-primary OpenSaleModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#AddSaleModal">Add Statistics</button>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-border table-hover table-sm= mb-5" id="OrderTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Player's Name</th>
          <th>Number of Goals</th>
          <th>Number of Assists</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-start text-center">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Erling Total</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="display-1 fw-bold" id="ETotal">0</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Phil Total</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="display-1 fw-bold" id="PTotal">0</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Jack Total</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="display-1 fw-bold" id="JTotal">0</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Total Together</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="display-1 fw-bold" id="TotalEveryone">0</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- TOASTS -->
  <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x p-3">
    <div class="toast align-items-center text-bg-success border-0" id="AddOrderToast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="toast-body fs-6">
          You successfully added data!
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close pe-3" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x p-3">
    <div class="toast align-items-center text-bg-success border-0" id="DeleteOrderToast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="toast-body fs-6">
          You successfully removed data!
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close pe-3" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal - Add Stats -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="AddSaleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add a New Statistic</h5>
          <button type="button" id="CloseEditClientModal" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="PlayerName" class="form-label">Choose A Player</label>
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="PlayerName">
              <option selected>Select from list...</option>
              <option value="Erling">Erling Haaland</option>
              <option value="Phil">Phil Foden</option>
              <option value="Jack">Jack Grealish</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a Player.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="GoalNum" class="form-label">Goals</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="GoalNum">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter a Goal number.
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="AssistQuantity" class="form-label">Assists</label>
              <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="AssistQuantity">
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter an Assist number.
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="AddSaleButton">Save Statistics</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've messed with the delete button, placement of lines of code, googling, changing and messing with the table. Can't find anything and I've talked to other struggling students. Same issue

Answer (score 1):

your javascript is looking for `<tbody>` inside the table `#OrderTable` but it could't find it.

```js
...
$('#OrderTable tbody').append(...)
...
```

solution:

```html
...
<table class="table table-border table-hover table-sm= mb-5" id="OrderTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player's Name</th>
            <th>Number of Goals</th>
            <th>Number of Assists</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody> <!--  add this line -->
</table>
...
```